# iCalendar TEXT Data Type - Preparing Values with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, icalendar

I am providing download links for my application's events.  One piece I am missing is how to prepare values for [the `TEXT` data type](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/text.html).  Specifically, the value that will end up with the `DESCRIPTION` property has HTML.  I have downloaded several PHP projects related to the iCalendar RFC, but I haven't tracked down a good snippet of code for preparing `TEXT` values.

---

I found a [blog entry](http://blog.cyandigital.com/2011/04/prepare-text-for-icalendar-file-with-php/) that was only [available in Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3agtGfjI38HhwJ%3ablog.cyandigital.com/2011/04/prepare-text-for-icalendar-file-with-php/%20php%20icalendar%20text&cd=7&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com) that had line wrapping, and I noticed that generating an ICS file from Outlook 2010 has line wrapping, but I'm going to leave it alone for now and come back to it if there's a problem.

I also decided to add support for the different possible line endings:

```
/**
 * Prepare data for a TEXT field
 *
 * @param string $text
 * @return string
 */
public static function prepareText($text)
{
    $search = array('\\', ';', ',', "\r\n", "\n", "\r");
    $replace = array('\\\\', '\;', '\,', '\n', '\n', '\n');
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the mixture of single and double quotes for the line break (Double quotes interpret the line breaks whereas single ones don't)

```
$text = 'Hello, World!
This is in a new line; after a semicolon/comma';
$search = array('/',';',',',"\N","\n");
$replace = array('\/','\;','\,','\n','\n');
$description = str_replace($search,$replace,$text);

print_r($description);
```

For sure this can be done with a probably easier RegExp..

Comment: I've also noticed code that "wraps" the lines if they go past a certain number of characters. Are you familiar with what that's about?

Comment: Can you post an reference link or file in your OP, the specification doesn't mention truncation?